# Template syntax to display breadcrumb for django-categories

Tags: django, django-templates

I have built a simple model with django-categories, in the models.py I have:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    # ...
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
```

In my views.py I have

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.order_by('pub_date').filter(category_id=2)
```

In my template 'blog/index.html' I have:

```
{% load category_tags %}
...
{% for blog in latest_article_list %}
  <li><a href="/uphero/{{ blog.id }}">{{ blog.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
...
```

I have created three categories:

```
blog
  |-- sub1
  |-- sub2
       |-- foo
       |-- bar
```

I have two questions:

1. In my views.py I used `.filter(category_id=3)` to return articles
   under `blog > sub2 > foo`, I'd really want to use
   `.filter(category='foo')` instead, but django reports "no attribute
   category" error, is there a workaround to use text version category name
   instead of by `id`?
2. I'd like to create a breadcrumb path on top of the page, for example:
   `blog > sub2 > foo`

Such that: category names are linkable; if the category contains subcategories, then display the list of subcategories; if the category contains no subcategories, then display the list of articles under that category.

I studies docs here https://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#breadcrumbs-tag but wasn't able to figure the correct syntax.

Can someone help me out on these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the following query should work:

```
.filter(category__name="foo")
```

Regarding your second question, you will need to create a view for each category. If you have already done this, please share your view and template code, so that we can help you.